Why the module index is in general only a fractional ideal?
I'am working in the $AKLB$ settings, so $A$ is a Dedekind domain, $K=\text{Frac}(A)$, $L/K$ a finite and separable extension and $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. Given $M,N$ free $A$-module of finite rank, contained in $K$-vector space $V$ of dimension $n$, such that $M,N$ generate (over $K$) $V$, i.e. $V=M\otimes_A K=N\otimes_A K$, then every $A$-base for $M$ (or $N$) is a $K$-base for $V$ and so $M\cong A^n\cong N$. Let $\psi:M\to N$ be an isomorphism of $A$-module, extend $\psi$ to $\hat{\psi}\in\text{Aut}_K(V)$ and define the module index as $[M:N]=\det{(\hat{\psi})}A$, this is a fractional ideal of $A$ and for example if $N\subset M$ it becomes an ideal of $A$.
I'am having some trouble understanding this definition. First, I suppose that given $\psi$, the extension to $V$ has the form
\begin{align}
\hat{\psi}:V\to V: m_i\otimes1\mapsto \psi(m_i)\otimes1,\,\,\,i\in\{1,\ldots n\},
\end{align}
where $\{m_i\}$ is a base for $M$ and then extending $\hat{\psi}$ by linearity we get the final extension map.
But the thing that bothers me is that I don't get why in general it's only a fractional ideal. If $\{m_i\}$ and $\{n_i\}$ are basis for $M,N$ respectively then $\hat{\psi}(m_i\otimes 1)=\psi(m_i)\otimes 1= (\sum a_jn_j)\otimes 1= \sum a_i (n_i\otimes 1)$ with $a_j\in A$ for every $j$ and so the matrix (and therefore the determinant) of $\hat{\psi}$ is in $A$.
Now if $N\subset M$ then every $n_i$ is a $A$-linear combination of the base $\{m_j\}$ and now it should follow that the matrix of $\hat{\psi}$ is in $A$, but I can't see how to conclude from this.
Of course my argument on $\hat{\psi}$ should be wrong but I don't know where.
Any help? Thanks.

I think you might have misunderstanding.
Here both $M$ and $N$ are free $A$-submodule of $V$, and we fix the $\{m_i\}$ as the $A$-base for $M$. Let $n_i=\psi (m_i)$. Then you can prove that $\{n_i\}$ is a $A$-base of $N$. Because  both $\{m_i\}$ and $\{n_i\}$ are $K$-base for $V$, you can assume that $m_i=\sum a_{ij}n_j$. Note that such $a_{ij}$ may not in $A$. Then $\mathrm{det}(\hat{\psi})=\mathrm{det}((a_{ij})_{n\times n})\in K$.
In the case that $N\subset M$, it is correct that $\mathrm{det}(\hat{\psi})\in A$. In general, this might be incorrect. For example, if you swap $M$ and $N$ here.

Ok, that helps a lot. But where is the error in what I wrote about $\hat{\psi}$? Can't I a priori take a base of $M$ and a base of $N$ and then take the associated matrix?

@Radagast: In fact, the value of $\mathrm{det}(\hat{\psi})$ is independent of the choice of basis of $M$ and $N$. If you want to calculate the determinant of a linear map, you need to fix a basis of the linear space. Although you assume that $\psi(m_i)=\sum a_j N_j$, it is incorrect to calculate determinant  this matrix because you have changed the basis( in fact ,the determinant of this matrix must be invertible in $A$ because ${\psi(m_i)} $ and ${n_i}$ are both $A$-basis of $N$).

Right, silly question. I forgot how to compute the determinant of a linear map. Sorry for that, thanks.
